# Bias T with pulse train

Tags: rf, signal, bias

I want to bias my pulser output which is 0 to 30V pulse train.
(Which means I want to make 30 to 60V pulses)

First, I used a bias T with 30V DC input:

[image]

I found that it works as a differentiator which gives the pulse train a negative offset so I can't get 30 to 60V pulse.

Is there any solution to make the pulse train to be biased as I want?

Comment: Use a 45V bias?

Comment: I can use 30V bias only..

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Apply 45 V to the DC arm of the tee instead of of 30 V. You'll have to adjust this value if the duty cycle of the pulsed input is not 50%.

Option 2: Add a diode to the DC arm like so:
[image]

[image]

Note: the output of this circuit could drop, depending how it is loaded.

Comment: how option2 works? I think it still acts as a differentiator since it is connected to capacitor

Comment: @WW Now it can only go in one direction. The capacitor charges and then it doesn't discharge